# Python SQLModel - Truncate table or delete all and get number of rows

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlmodel

Using Python SQLModel, I want to truncate a table, or remove all rows, and get the number of deleted rows, in the most SQLModel standar way. How can I do this? I am using this:

```py
        with Session(engine) as session:
            count = session.exec(delete(MyModel)).fetchall()
            session.commit()
```

But it raises an error:

```
ResourceClosedError('This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.')
```

I have also tried `scalar()` and `fetchone()` instead of `fetchall()` without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with Session(engine) as session:
    statement = delete(MyModel)
    result = session.exec(statement)
    session.commit()
    print(result.rowcount)
```

[Matched Row Counts](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#matched-row-counts)